# Symfony2 - How to change a document using a postLoad event-listener with Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I have a document which describes a model in my app,
I want to change a field value after the document is loaded, I figured out that the way to do it is with event listener.
I added a new listener (postLoad listener) in my config/services.yml, I can't figure out how to get the document and change it before it is being sent.

help would be appreciated. :)

This is what I added to config/service.yml (under service)

```
core.listener:
  class: Matan\CoreBundle\EventListener\DocumentListener
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

DocumentListener.php

```
namespace Matan\CoreBundle\EventListener;

use Matan\CoreBundle\Document\App;

class DocumentListener
{
    public function postLoad()
    {
        //I Want to change it here
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some code :)

Comment: I updated my original message with the code, thanks!

Comment: Now what exactly do you want to change ? ... and based on what conditions?

Comment: I want to check if the document that is being loaded is of type App and if so I want to change the document using his own getters, the question is how can I access the document from inside the postLoad method.

Comment: Please see my answer and report back if anything is left unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**solution:**

You should specify the listener's method that shall be called in your service definition:

```
- { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener, event: postLoad, method: onPostLoad }
```

Now you can get the document that has just been loaded from the **[EventArgs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Event.LifecycleEventArgs.html)** passed to the `onPostLoad` method.

check if it matches the model you want to change, then perform your changes.

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Acme\Your\Document\MyDocument;

public function onPostLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{   
    $document = $eventArgs->getDocument();

    if !($document instanceof MyDocument) {
       return;
    }

    // ... your code here
    // $document->setLoaded(new \Date('now'));
}
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#registering-event-listeners-and-subscribers): Unlike Symfony2 event listeners, Doctrine's event manager expects each listener and subscriber to have a method name corresponding to the observed event(s). For this reason, the aforementioned tags have no method attribute.